# Why isn't the mysql database updating in this case?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, pdo, str-replace

I have this PHP script:

```
require_once('global.php'); //connects to db and various functions used
//select the user's information
$statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=1");
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchObject();
//get the chat
$string = $result->chats;

$from = $_REQUEST['from'];
$msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];
$sent = $_REQUEST['sent'];

//see what we should do with the recieved data
if($string == "") {
    //there isnt any chats right now, we must add the first ever contact
    $string = "<ResultSet><chats><chat><messages><sms><from>{$from}</from><msg>{$msg}</msg><sent>{$sent}</sent></sms></messages><contact>{$from}</contact></chat></chats></ResultSet>";
    //send the data back to the user's row in the database
    $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE user SET chats='{$string}' WHERE id=1");
    $statement->execute();
} else if($from == $result->name) {
    //the user is sending a message to a contact. we now need to get the "to" value.
    $to = trim(str_replace("_", " ", $_REQUEST['to']));
    //add the sms to the contact's chat
    $string = str_replace("</sms></messages><contact>{$to}</contact>", "</sms><sms><from>{$from}</from><msg>{$msg}</msg><sent>{$sent}</sent></sms></messages><contact>{$to}</contact>", $string);
    //send the data back to the user's row in the database
    $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE user SET chats='{$string}' WHERE id=1");
    $statement->execute();
} else if(strstr($string, "<contact>".$from."</contact>")) {
    //The contact that sent the message already exists in this user's row, add the message to the contact's chat
    $string = str_replace("</sms></messages><contact>{$from}</contact>", "</sms><sms><from>{$from}</from><msg>{$msg}</msg><sent>{$sent}</sent></sms></messages><contact>{$from}</contact>", $string);
    //send the data back to the user's row in the database
    $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE user SET chats='{$string}' WHERE id=1");
    $statement->execute();
} else {
    //Person who sent the message doesnt exist in the chats, add him.
    $string = str_replace("</chats>", "<chat><messages><sms><from>{$from}</from><msg>{$msg}</msg><sent>{$sent}</sent></sms></messages><contact>{$from}</contact></chat></chats>", $string);
    //send the data back to the user's row in the database
    $statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE user SET chats='{$string}' WHERE id=1");
    $statement->execute();
}
```

The problem is in this else if code:

```
else if($from == $result->name) {
//the user is sending a message to a contact. we now need to get the "to" value.
$to = trim(str_replace("_", " ", $_REQUEST['to']));
//add the sms to the contact's chat
$string = str_replace("</sms></messages><contact>{$to}</contact>", "</sms><sms><from>{$from}</from><msg>{$msg}</msg><sent>{$sent}</sent></sms></messages><contact>{$to}</contact>", $string);
//send the data back to the user's row in the database
$statement = $db->prepare("UPDATE user SET chats='{$string}' WHERE id=1");
$statement->execute();
}
```

I am sure the code is running through this else, I have echo'd and confirmed. When I use the $string  = str_replace(), I printed the $string and it had indeed replaced. But when I submit the data to the row in the database, nothing happens when I refresh my db. Why does it not work for this else but does for the rest of the if statement (and the if before it)?

It doesn't make sense to me. The code I tried my best to comment it appropriately, if you need something explained just ask.

Comment: fyi, your code is susceptible to sql injection.

Comment: Your comment to code ratio is almost 1:1

Comment: I'd say that 99% of the code is obvious to someone knowing mysql and a little php without the comments

Comment: None of the comments above was helpful neither is this one... (except maybe for the sql injection one)

Comment: Not really worried about sql injection, I am using Mysql PDO so it automatically protects it.

Comment: @Qasim *NO IT DOESN'T* when you stick stuff straight into the query like you are: `UPDATE user SET chats='{$string}'`. Re-read [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: @Treffynnon this is for personal use so does this even matter?

Comment: @Qasim That is entirely up to you, but I would definitely change your code to use proper PDO parameters no matter what. I am not telling you what you can and cannot do. I am just giving you guidance on what I believe is the correct way. Plus it is very dangerous for you to think something just automagically protects you when in fact it does not should you ever produce code that makes it onto the web in any form.

Comment: @Treffynnon Sorry I had a guide that told me it would do this automatically, I'll have to read up I guess. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why but I had to change my code up so  Iwould send the variables in the execute function instead of in the query. In the query I would put "?" where I want the variables, and in the execute() function I would put an array like

```
$statement->execute(array($string, 1));
```

That seems to have fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In case $db is not an instance of MySQLi or PDO but a db wrapper, look at the class that is instantiated as $db and make sure it doesn't start a transaction. If there is a transaction initiated, you will need to commit the transaction so that the changes to the database are applied/saved.

Comment: It is indeed PDO, so I am really clueless as to why this is happening :(

Comment: can you also post any code in the global.php that is related to $db?

Comment: `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=********_web', '********_***', '*****************');` And there are no errors on connection

Comment: do you have something like $db->beginTransaction(); ?

Comment: Nope, in global.php that is the only line that uses the PDO class :)

Comment: add the following at the beginning of the file $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, true);

Comment: Like this? `$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=*******_web', '*******', '*******');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, true);`